# Filling NAs to string 0 and then to int reverts to float

Tags: python, pandas, dask, nan

What I want here is for the Nans to ultimately be integer values. Since my dataset is 1000s of columns, I can't just change a couple of columns to make them integer and when I tried `df = df.astype('int')` in Dask, after changing the values to 0 floats, for whatever reason, it didn't work. `

While the values below have all reverted to floats in Pandas; in Dask, only some of the columns' zero values reverted to floats. I figure if I can solve this issue in Pandas, then likely it will also solve it in Dask (Fingers crossed).

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['tom', 10, 15000], ['nick', 15, 12000], ['juli', 5, 20000]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'salary'])

import numpy as np
df = df.replace(5, np.nan)
df = df.replace(12000, np.nan)

expanded = df.replace(np.nan, '0')
expanded = expanded.replace('0', 0)
expanded
```

Comment: When you `replace` with a value that isn't capable of being stored within the current dtype of that Series (np.NaN is a float, so can't be held in a Series with an int dtype) `replace` is _smart_ enough to upcast that column to a resonable dtype that can hold those values. It won't automatically downcast if you replace and allow all values to fit into a more limited dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
from dask.dataframe import from_pandas
ddf = from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

out = ddf.select_dtypes('number').fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

Output:

```
>>> out.compute()
   Age  salary
0   10   15000
1   15       0
2    0   20000
```

Comment: It seems to have changed everything to integer zeros...running the regression now. I had to wait a minute before accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks also for including it in Dask! So I think this is a related issue, and since it seems like you have a good understanding of Dask, while running the regression, I get this error: ```Multiple constant columns detected!``` I've looked through the posts on SO, and I know that it has something to do with estimating std, but these are binary integer values, so why would it be doing that? I'll read more about what people are saying, whether it can be overridden, but thought I'd post here to see whether you've come across that.

Comment: Maybe you can drop all columns with all values are 0?

Comment: Yeah, I actually did that (there weren't any columns with all zero).